# add error method returning a null pointer exception

Tags: apex, trigger, error, before-trigger

In a `before insert` trigger I added an `addError` message, but the error message is not showing, instead I get a `NullPointerException`. This is my code:

```
trigger ValidateNIF on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for (Account a : trigger.new){
        String nif = a.NIF__c;
        id accId = a.Id;
            if (nif.length() != 9){
                trigger.newmap.get(accId).addError('The field Nif must contain 9 digists!');
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `before insert` event `Id` of record is not defined for record. that is why you have NPE here `trigger.newmap.get(accId).addError;`, as  `trigger.newmap.get(accId)` returns `null`. There is no need to get account to which you want add error as `trigger.newmap.get(accId).addError`

your logic can be re-written in the following way:

```
trigger ValidateNIF on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for (Account a : trigger.new){
        if (String.isNotBlank(a.NIF__c) && a.NIF__c.length() != 9){
            a.addError('The field Nif must contain 9 digists!');
        }
    }
}
```

maybe it is better to create validation rule that checks length of `NIF__c` field ?

Comment: I have other conditions to check, but maybe that is a good alternative. Thank you!

Answer (score -4):

```
trigger ValidateNIF on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for (Account a : trigger.new){
        String nif = a.NIF__c != Null ? a.NIF__c : '';
            if (nif.length()  != 9){
                a.addError('The field Nif must contain 9 digists!');
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not solicit "accept answer" votes within any answer you post here. Answers should contain only information relevant to the question being asked. A good question will also include an *explanation*, not just code.

Comment: I always ignore people who don't understand what is expected. And I dont answer more than expected. If anything wrong in my answer plese point I will definitely correct myself.

Comment: I did explain exactly what is wrong with your answer. I already took the first step for you (removing your request for the OP to accept your answer). You must take the second step yourself in adding an explanation of why your code might resolve their issue.

Comment: I was not expecting more than that from you :)